# having some issues installing sencha touch 2 on mac book

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I downloaded Sencha touch from this [link](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/download/sencha-touch-2.1/) `Download for 2.1 GPL`. Then I extracted to XAMPP/htdocs folder. Then I downloaded Senchatouch sdk tools from this [link](http://www.sencha.com/products/sdk-tools/download). I installed it in /Applications folder. Then in `Terminal` I `cd` to `Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3`. Here I run `sencha` command. But it displays following output in screenshot

[image]

I also checked PATH which shows following output

[image]

I searched all over internet to find its solution but none of them worked for me.

I also followed following links

[link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10508857/sencha-touch-2-cannot-find-module-sencha-sdk-dir-command-sencha-js)
[link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291742/warn-the-current-working-directory-c-xampp-htdocs-sencha-folder-is-not-a-re)

Please help me how can I solve it?

**UPDATE**

After following @TDeBailleul I am getting the same error which is follow.

[image]

I first installed JRE then compass and then senchaCmd. I installed senchaCmd in `/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/sencha/` folder. Then I download Sencha Touch SDK form this [link](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/download/sencha-touch-2.1/). Then I `cd` to `Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/senchatouch/Sencha/Cmd/3.0.0.250/` and issued `sencha` command but got above output again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **Sencha Command** and not **Sencha SDK Tools** with Sencha Touch 2.1

Take a look at my answer here :

[Generate a sencha touch app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13497247/generate-a-sencha-touch-app/13500700#13500700)

Hop this helps

Comment: THank you for you reply. Please see my update above. I am still getting the same error.

Comment: You need to go to the SDK Folder not the SenchaCmd folder to execute sencha command

Comment: you mean this `sencha-touch-2.1.0-gpl` folder which I which I extracted from .zip file?